# Hide multiple ranges of rows based on different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working script. It is slow due to hiding rows 1 by 1.

I need to hide 58 rows per loop. I know it is possible to hide a range of rows and made it work but only for the first 58 rows. It doesn't hide the next 58.

There is in total 1740 rows so I am hiding up to 1740 times instead of 30 times.

The goal of the script is to hide rows as to not print this part of the worksheet, there is in total 30 sheet of paper that can be printed in this worksheet. Each sheet is 58 rows and what determines if the sheet is to be printed is if cell I3, for the first sheet, has a text or if it is empty or have a space, the next sheet is I63, then I119 and so on.

[image]

This code is hiding rows 1 by 1:

```vb
Sub Hide_column_and_Row_FR_3_XX_Fiche_Erreur()

Dim NbreLigne As Integer
Dim hh As Variant
Dim zz As Variant
Dim tableau As range

Set wrkshtDoc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-XX_Fiche d'erreur")
Set tableau = wrkshtDoc.range("A1:L1740")
hh = 1
   
NbreLigne = tableau.Rows.Count

For k = 3 To NbreLigne
   
    If tableau(k, 9) = " " Or tableau(k, 9) = Empty Then
        For zz = 1 To 58
            wrkshtDoc.Rows(hh).Hidden = True
            hh = hh + 1
        Next zz
                  
    Else
        For zz = 1 To 58
            wrkshtDoc.Rows(hh).Hidden = False
            hh = hh + 1
        Next zz
    End If
        
    k = k + 57
          
Next k
End Sub
```

I tried different ways to select multiple rows but it always ends up being blocked behind

> missing object

I can do code inside a cell in a worksheet but VBA is different. I tried to reuse as much code as possible that was already in this document to make something.

---

I tweaked Scott's code as there was a glitch and now is working much faster than the old code:

```vb
    ub Hide_column_and_Row_FR_3_XX_Fiche_Erreur()

    Dim NbreLigne As Long
    Dim tableau As range
    
    Set wrkshtDoc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-XX_Fiche d'erreur")
    Set tableau = wrkshtDoc.range("A1:L1740")
    
    NbreLigne = tableau.Rows.Count
    
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 1 To NbreLigne Step 58
        tableau(k, 1).Resize(58, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (tableau(k + 2, 9) = " " Or tableau(k + 2, 9) = Empty)
    Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Step to step 58 rows at a time and Resize to pick up all 58 rows:

```
Sub Hide_column_and_Row_FR_3_XX_Fiche_Erreur()

    Dim NbreLigne As Long
    Dim tableau As Range
    
    
    Set wrkshtDoc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-XX_Fiche d'erreur")
    Set tableau = wrkshtDoc.Range("A1:L1740")
    
    NbreLigne = tableau.Rows.Count
    
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 3 To NbreLigne Step 58
        tableau(k, 9).Resize(58, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (tableau(k, 9) = " " Or tableau(k, 9) = Empty)
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it is much faster than the current code, the only thing currently is that it miss only 1 row, the top row ''Modification en cour d'assemblage / test''. For example if i print this worsheet with only 1 sheet out of 30 to be printed, there will be 2 sheet printed at the end. i didn't know about resize so i'm gonna try and take a look tomorrow for the row that don't hide. thank you for this code.

Comment: i found what was causing the small glitch and now is working like a charm, posted the revised code